I am unable to choose a build in Appstoreconnect. The builds show up, but are disabled. No Error is displayed, what could be the reason?
I have uploaded many builds to appstoreconnect before, but have never encountered this issue:

The build is uploaded successfully from xcode to appstoreconnect
The build becomes available in Testflight and can be donwloaded from there. Eveything works great through Testflight internal testing. (I also receive the usual email with the title "App name for iOS is now available to test.")
When trying to choose any build on the Distribution tab to submit the App for review, I see all the builds which are also available to download through Testflight
--> However all those builds appear disabled in the UI and I am unable to select them. There is no error shown whatsoever. This can be observed in the following Screenshot:


Does anyone have an idea what the reason/issue could be here? Did anyone encounter this before?

Your app version is "1.0". None of your builds have that version. "1.0.0" is not the same as "1.0"

Adjusting the version to 1.0.0 didn't change anything. (Also those never had to match in other apps I released.)

There was actually an issue which apple had with the build itself. The build was running perfectly fine and downloadable through Testflight, but the developer who uploaded the build with Xcode received an email which outlined some kind of issue.
So in case you run into this:

Find the developer who uploaded the build (if you are lucky this is you )
Tell that developer to search for an email from Apple with the title "The uploaded build for YOUR_APP_NAME has one or more issues."
Within that email you should find information on what exactly Apple does not like with the build.

I've no idea why the issues with the build are not shown within Appstoreconnect or at least sent to every developer and app manager of that app. It seems very weird for me that it is necessary to hunt for an email which is only sent to one specific developer.
Note that the build being downloadable through Testflight and receiving the Email with the title "YOUR_APP_NAME x.y.z (BUILD_NUMBER) is ready to test on iOS." is no guarantee that the same build can be sent in for the actual store review.
